# passing value from panda dataframe to http request

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-functions

I'm not sure how I should ask this question. I'm looping through a csv file using panda (at least I think so). As I'm looping through rows, I want to pass a value from a specific column to run an http request for each row.

Here is my code so far:

```
def api_request(request): 
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)
    with fs.open('gs://project.appspot.com/file.csv') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f,)
        value = df[['ID']].to_string(index=False)
        print(value)
        response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL + value,headers={'accept': 'application/json','ClientToken':TOKEN }
        )
        json_response = response.json()
        print(json_response)
```

As you can see, I'm looping through the csv file to get the ID to pass it to my request url.

I'm not sure I understand the issue but looking at the console log it seems that `print(value)` is in the loop when the response request is not. In other words, in the console log I'm seeing all the ID printed but I'm seeing only one http request which is empty (probably because the ID is not correctly passed to it).

I'm running my script with cloud functions.

Comment: You're not looping anything at all though.  Did you mean to do `for value in df['ID']: response = requests.get(...)`? What do you see from `print(value)`?

Comment: I think I'm misinterpreting my console log output. I'm seeing all the value (`df[['ID']]`) printed one after the other from my csv file... like if I was looping through it.

Comment: `.to_string(...)` makes it a string representation of the items, but it's really just *one* iteration of *every ID*.  If you want to deal with them one by one, you need to loop them with `for`.

Comment: `df[['ID']].to_string(index=False)` is giving you the entire column as a string at once. You need to index into or loop over the column to get the individual data elements

Comment: @Parfait would it be more simple with `csv` module? I'll be happy to have a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try instead:

```
def api_request(request): 
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)
    with fs.open('gs://project.appspot.com/file.csv') as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        for value in df['ID']:
            response = requests.get(
                REQUEST_URL + value,
                headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'ClientToken': TOKEN }
            )
            json_response = response.json()
            print(json_response)
```

As mentioned in my comment, you haven't iterated through the data.  What you are seeing is just the string representation of it with linebreaks (which might be why you mistakenly thought to be looping).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, forgo the use of the Pandas library and simply iterate through csv

```
import csv

def api_request(request): 
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)
    with fs.open('gs://project.appspot.com/file.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader, None)                 # SKIP HEADERS

        for row in reader:                 # LOOP THROUGH GENERATOR (NOT PANDAS SERIES)
            value = row[0]                 # SELECT FIRST COLUMN (ASSUMED ID)
            response = requests.get(
                 REQUEST_URL + value,
                 headers={'accept': 'application/json', 'ClientToken': TOKEN }
            )     
            json_response = response.json()
            print(json_response)
```